# IS NULL vs = NULL in where clause + SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to check a value `IS NULL [or] = @param` (where @param is null)

Ex:

```
Select column1 from Table1
where column2 IS NULL => works fine
```

If I want to replace comparing value (IS NULL) with @param. How can this be done

```
Select column1 from Table1
where column2 = @param => this works fine until @param got some value in it and if is null never finds a record.
```

How can this achieve?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
select column1 from Table1
  where (@param is null and column2 is null)
     or (column2 = @param)
```

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an old question, but I had the same one, and came up with another (shorter) answer. *Note: this may only work for MS SQL Server, which supports ISNULL(expr,replacement).*

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1
WHERE ISNULL(column2,'') = ISNULL(@param,'')
```

This also assumes you treat NULL and empty strings the same way.

Comment: If you changed your SQL to use COALESCE instead of ISNULL then it would work for more than just SQL Server since the former is ISO/ANSI defined unlike the latter.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "one size fits all" query approach for this, there are subtle performance implications in how you do this.  If you would like to go *beyond* just making the query return the proper answer, no matter how slow it is, look at this article on [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQLby Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

here is a link to the portion on [x = @x OR @x IS NULL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#OR_ISNULL)

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE ((COLUMN1 = @PARAM) OR (COLUMN1 IS NULL AND @PARAM IS NULL))
```

Comment: `COLUMN = @PARAM` will never be true if `@PARAM` is null, so the second condition (`@PARAM IS NOT NULL`) is redundant.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Jun  You're Right, I removed the redundant code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Select column1 from Table1
where (column2 IS NULL and @param IS NULL) 
or ( column2 IS NOT NULL AND @param IS NOT NULL AND ( column2 = @param )  )
```

Comment: The `column2 IS NOT NULL` check is unnecessary, since this would be covered by `column2 = @param`... which makes this answer a less concise version of the accepted answer from last year.

Comment: the answer from last year had this: (@param is null and column2 is null) or (column2 = @param)
If the @param is not null, the first condition would be false, and the 2nd would be evaluated only: (column2 = @param)
I have found that if you are checking things like (column2 = @param) and it could be null, the extra check is safer to have