# Why doesn't "WHERE column = NULL" throw an error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IS NULL vs = NULL in where clause + SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490117/is-null-vs-null-in-where-clause-sql-server)

Consider the following code – can someone explain to me why the one query doesn’t throw an error? I can understand why it doesn’t return a record, but what is it trying to do? Remember that colA is an int. It works the same on 2000,2005 and 2008 r2

```
create table #foo
( colA int )


insert into #foo
(colA)
values
(null)

select * from #foo --returns the one record we just created

select * from #foo where colA = null --does not throw an error and does not return a record! why??
select * from #foo where colA is null --returns the record

drop table #foo
```

Is there ever record that could exist in this table that would return for colA = null?

I dont have any other databases available to me at the moment to try this out - is this standard or is it behavior specific to MSSQL?

Comment: as a side question, if anyone has a better suggestion for a title for this question let me know - I struggled with how to put it.

Comment: This has been addressed multiple times before...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833949/why-is-null-not-equal-to-null-false

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078837/why-doesnt-sql-support-null-instead-of-is-null

Comment: @JNK - The OP is asking why the syntax doesn't prohibit it. Not for an explanation of the behaviour.

Comment: ..and -1 for not searching for something like `SQL SERVER NULL` which will turn up 5 dupes in the first page.

Comment: While extremely similar, the question here is "Why doesn't it throw an error?'

Comment: Yet the answers are the same: **NULL IS A NON-VALUE**.  You have to allow `=` with `NULL` if you allow mixed `NULL` and non-`NULL` fields.

Comment: @JNK - But you don't have to allow it for the literal `NULL`. With `ANSI_NULLS ON` it could cause a compile time error same as dividing by the literal `0`.

Comment: Although of course my divide by 0 point is a bad one as that would cause a run time error and it would be very odd to have something that caused an error at compile time but was allowed at run time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because a NULL can't be equated to any value.

Disable the ANSI_NULLS option and then run it you will see the row now:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
select * from #foo --returns the one record we just created  
select * from #foo where colA = null --does not throw an error and does not return a record! why?? 
select * from #foo where colA is null --returns the record  drop table #foo
```

Comment: I think its also interesting to note that SET ANSI_NULL is to be [removed from future version of sql server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) (and not just deprecated like in SQL Server 2008). So the usage of `=` against a `NULL` is not recommanded.

Answer (score 4):

You can force the behavior by using `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;` but since this is deprecated and makes the code rely on a SET setting that can't always be guaranteed, the real solution is to use the right syntax (the one that returns the row).

Answer (score 3):

It does not throw an error because it is not an invalid query. The problem is that `NULL` represents the absence of data and you can't have anything that is equal to that. So when you do

```
select * from #foo where colA = null
```

it does try to find rows where `colA = null`, but that's just impossible. Therefore no errors and no results.

Comment: Yes. I suppose it is not invalid (even with `ANSI_NULLS ON` where it makes no sense) for the same reason as `WHERE 1=2` does not throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

[`NULL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) is a special value in RDBMS that means an unknown or inapplicable value.

So nothing will ever be `= NULL`; such comparison is not valid, thus any queries with `expr = NULL` in their `WHERE` clause will return no rows.

Of course this has its quirks and some implementations do things differently; eg: Oracle treats empty strings (`''`) as `NULL` and gets quite a bit grief for that.

SQL Server has the [`ANSI NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) parameter that makes it compliant with SQL-92 (eg comparisons with `NULL`s like you did won't work.

Comment: More along the lines of `(anything = null)` evaluates to null, so effectively, the where clause is literally seen as `... WHERE null`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why and for what reason the = operator does not support null values but in mysql there is another operator that does: "<=>"
Only works in mysql though.